# AWS S3 getting presigned URL Guzzle "argument must be of type array, object given" when it's an array

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I don't understand why this doesn't work, and I have scoured the Internet and can't find anything matching my specific command I'm using.

I am basically trying to generate a presigned URL from Amazon S3 and I am following the directions in the docs to a T and it's not working.. Actually not to a T, I was doing it to a T. The docs say to make the array like this : [ 'Key' => 'Value' ] ... I saw another question here where the solved answer was to make it using array() .... but it doesn't change anything.

It still gives this error:

> [01-Jan-2016 13:28:56 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Guzzle\Service\Client::getCommand() must be of the type array, object given, called in /Users/alex/Development/theshrineofdionysus-com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on line 76 and defined in /Users/alex/Development/theshrineofdionysus-com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on line 79

This is the code I am using related to the S3 part of it. Trust me when I saw the constants regarding the keys, region and bucket are correct, as I have other S3 code using them elsewhere that works flawlessly.

```
<?php
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
  'key'    => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  'region' => AWS_REGION,
));
$cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', array(
  'Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET,
  'Key' => $row['video_id']
));
$request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+120 minutes');
$url = (string) $request->getUri();
?>
```

I also know that $row['video_id'] is equal to an existing filename because without this code there, and I'm echoing it out it is the correct filename.

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "php": ">=5.2.0"
    }
}
```

This is my amazon code on the other page that works fine:

```
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
  'key'    => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  'region' => AWS_REGION
));
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET));
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  echo '<option value="' . $object['Key'] . '">' . $object['Key'] . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're following the guide for v3 but have v2 installed. You can create a presigned URL in v2 by calling: `$url = $s3->getObjectUrl(AWS_BUCKET, $row['video_id'], '+120 minutes');`

A full guide can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#creating-a-pre-signed-url).

Comment: I didn't know it was because a guide for v3 but I did figure this out. Thanks for the answer!